# How to store doubles in a point?

Tags: java, point

I am trying to create several points in a java program. The coordinates of the points are in a text file, which I scan in and read number by number.

```
   double x = 0.0;
   double y = 0.0;

   Point origin = new Point(x, y);
   Point[] points = new Point[1000]; // There are 1000 points in total, thus 2000 doubles, this array will be used to store all the points

   Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
   String FileName = keyboard.nextLine();       
   Scanner linReader = new Scanner(new File(FileName));

   while (linReader.hasNextDouble()) {     
       x = linReader.nextDouble();
       y = linReader.nextDouble(); 

       origin = (x, y); // error telling me 'cannot convert from double to point'
       }
```

I get the error "cannot convert from double to a point" so I need to know how to I fix this error? Am I allowed to use doubles coordinates for points?

Comment: What methods have you written in your `Point` class?  Are there any with names like `setX` and `setY`?

Comment: No, I don't even have a point class. I wasn't aware that I needed one. Could you explain further?

Comment: So you're importing a `Point` class from some library somewhere?  Which one?  Is there an `import` statement at the top of your code that mentions `Point`?

Comment: Yeah, I have 3: import java.util.*;, import java.io.*;, import java.lang.reflect.Array;

Comment: OK, none of those imports will give you a `Point` class.  Perhaps you have one in the same directory as your source code?  Or perhaps you're actually imported `java.awt.*` as well?  It has a class called `Point`, but it doesn't store `double` values.

Answer (score 3):

`Point` class won't give the double precision. For the double precision you need to use [**Point2D.Double**](https://www.cs.rit.edu/usr/local/jdk/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Point2D.Double.html) class. Consider the following code as example.

```
    static void pointTest() {
      double x = 1.2;
      double y = 3.4;
      Point2D.Double pointDouble = new Point2D.Double(x, y);
      System.out.println(pointDouble);
    }
```

Comment: If double precision is needed ` Point2D.Double` is a good choice. Otherwise you can cast double to float. +1

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void  main(String args[]) {

    //// Alternative 1 
    double x = 9.7;
    double y = 8.6;

    //import com.sun.javafx.geom.Point2D;
    Point2D point2D = new Point2D();
    point2D.x = (float) x; point2D.y= (float) y;


    ///// Alternative 2 (lose some accuracy) 
    //use Double object   
    Double x1 = 9.7;
    Double y1 = 8.6;
    //import java.awt.Point;
    Point origin = new Point(x1.intValue(), y1.intValue());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this class:

```
import org.springframework.data.geo.Point;
```

maven:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: How is your answer related to this question?

Answer (score -1):

Seems more straightforward to do it like this:

```
List<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>(1000);

...

    points.add(new Point(x, y));
```

Comment: Using which `Point` class?

Comment: The `Point` class he is already using based on the code he has provided and which clearly has a constructor that takes x and y `double` arguments. Why don't you suggest a solution so we can vote on it?

Answer (score -1):

Heres a minimum change solution:

```
   double x = 0.0;
   double y = 0.0;

   Point origin;
   Point[] points = new Point[1000]; // There are 1000 points in total, thus 2000 doubles, this array will be used to store all the points

   Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
   String FileName = keyboard.nextLine();       
   Scanner linReader = new Scanner(new File(FileName));

   while (linReader.hasNextDouble()) {     
       x = linReader.nextDouble();
       y = linReader.nextDouble(); 

       origin  = new Point(x, y);
       }
```

You could also implement your own Point class something like this

```
    public class Point {

      double x;
      double y;

     public Point(double x, double y){
       this.x = x;
       this.y = y;
     }

     public double getX(){
       return this.x;          
     }

     public double getY(){
       return this.y;          
     }
   }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: It would be easier to guide if you could show the structure of this `Point` class

Comment: It would be easier to guide him if you didn't just guess about what his `Point` class is and what constructors it has.